# Utility Method: Translate Year String to an Integer Representation

Tags: apex

We have a method we use to pass in an Integer and convert it to a string version of the year we want:

```
public static String translateYear(Integer numYrsRequested) {
   return String.Valueof(Date.Today().Year() - numYrsRequested);
}
```

- 0 = Current Year
- 1 = Last Year
- 2 = Two Years Ago (etc.)

Its late and I don't quite know how I would reverse this but need to. Any one got a quick solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public static Integer reverseTranslateYear(String year){
   return Date.Today().Year() - Integer.ValueOf(year); 
}
```